# Sublist filenames based on parent folder and partially similar names

Tags: python, list, text, split, sublist

I have the following list:

```
mesh_files = ['../data/Tombstone1.obj', '../data/Tombstone1_p1.obj', '../data/Tombstone1_p2.obj', '../data/Tombstone2.obj', '../data/box_8/frag_1__final.ply', '../data/box_8/frag_1_final.ply', '../data/box_8/frag_2__final.ply', '../data/box_8/frag_2_final.ply', '../data/box_8/frag_3__final.ply', '../data/box_8/frag_3_final.ply', '../data/frag_1__final.ply', '../data/frag_1_final.ply', '../data/parasaurolophus_6700.ply']

print('\n'.join(mesh_files))
../data/Tombstone1.obj
../data/Tombstone1_p1.obj
../data/Tombstone1_p2.obj
../data/Tombstone2.obj
../data/box_8/frag_1__final.ply
../data/box_8/frag_1_final.ply
../data/box_8/frag_2__final.ply
../data/box_8/frag_2_final.ply
../data/box_8/frag_3__final.ply
../data/box_8/frag_3_final.ply
../data/frag_1__final.ply
../data/frag_1_final.ply
../data/parasaurolophus_6700.ply
```

Is there a fast/direct way to split the above list to the following sublists:

```
[['../data/Tombstone1.obj', '../data/Tombstone1_p1.obj', '../data/Tombstone1_p2.obj'], 
['../data/Tombstone2.obj'], 
['../data/box_8/frag_1__final.ply', '../data/box_8/frag_1_final.ply'], 
['../data/box_8/frag_2__final.ply', '../data/box_8/frag_2_final.ply'], 
['../data/box_8/frag_3__final.ply', '../data/box_8/frag_3_final.ply'], 
['../data/frag_1__final.ply', '../data/frag_1_final.ply'], 
['../data/parasaurolophus_6700.ply']]
```

As I see it, I would consider as conditions the parent folder and part of the filenames. However, I would like to avoid `for` loops.

Thanks.

Comment: you can try to use functions like `map`, `filter` but it is also some type of loop but you don't see this loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
import re, collections
def group(d, p=[]):
   c = collections.defaultdict(list)
   for a, *b in d:
      c[a].append(b)
   for a, b in c.items():
      if any(len(i) == 1 for i in b):
         v = [x for y in b for x in ([p+[a]+y] if len(y)==1 else group([y],p+[a]))]
         yield [j for k in v for j in ([k] if all(isinstance(i, str) for i in k) else k)]
      else:
         yield from group(b, p+[a])

mesh_files = ['../data/Tombstone1.obj', '../data/Tombstone1_p1.obj', '../data/Tombstone1_p2.obj', '../data/Tombstone2.obj', '../data/box_8/frag_1__final.ply', '../data/box_8/frag_1_final.ply', '../data/box_8/frag_2__final.ply', '../data/box_8/frag_2_final.ply', '../data/box_8/frag_3__final.ply', '../data/box_8/frag_3_final.ply', '../data/frag_1__final.ply', '../data/frag_1_final.ply', '../data/parasaurolophus_6700.ply']
r = list(group([re.findall('[a-zA-Z0-9]+', i) for i in mesh_files]))
n = iter(mesh_files)
result = [[next(n) for _ in k] for k in r]
```

Output:

```
[['../data/Tombstone1.obj', '../data/Tombstone1_p1.obj', '../data/Tombstone1_p2.obj'], 
 ['../data/Tombstone2.obj'], 
 ['../data/box_8/frag_1__final.ply', '../data/box_8/frag_1_final.ply'], 
 ['../data/box_8/frag_2__final.ply', '../data/box_8/frag_2_final.ply'], 
 ['../data/box_8/frag_3__final.ply', '../data/box_8/frag_3_final.ply'], 
 ['../data/frag_1__final.ply', '../data/frag_1_final.ply'], 
 ['../data/parasaurolophus_6700.ply']]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it seems to work nicely. Could you please elaborate a bit on the idea behind. Moreover, I have a use case scenario where I have additionally to the initial list the following extra filenames `[..., '../data/box_11/frag_4__final.ply', '../data/box_11/frag_4_final.ply', '../data/box_11/frag_4a_final.ply']` this gives me two sublists for these while I would like to have only one i.e. `[[...], [...], ['../data/box_11/frag_4__final.ply', '../data/box_11/frag_4_final.ply', '../data/box_11/frag_4a_final.ply']]`. Can this be addressed somehow. Thanks.